# How to properly treat feature branches and package interdependencies?

Tags: python, git, package, branch

While trying to stick to the branching model from [http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model  [image]
, i.e. using feature branches and merging them back into a develop-branch, I sometimes encounter the following situation:

Feature `base` (which is both a feature branch and a Python package), is considered complete and merged into `develop`. Now a feature (=branch&package) `stuff`, which requires `base`, is branched off and while developing that I realize that `stuff` needs some modifications/enhancements in `base` that should have been there from the very beginning. So in which branch should I modify the package `base`?

- Doing this in the branch `stuff` seems wrong since the modifications of `base` should become part of `dev` no matter when (and if) `stuff` is merged back.
- (Re)branching to `base`, modifying, merging into both `develop` and `stuff` will on the other hand create many merges and I'm not sure whether it is good practice to merge *into* a feature branch. Especially if it's only a minor yet important modification
- And committing twice (via `git cherry-pick`) also doesn't feel right.
- Turning `base` into a `git submodule` sounds like overkill
- Rebasing `stuff` onto an updated `develop` will make history look nicer, but causes the usual problems should others have pulled the original branch `stuff` - not a problem in my single-developer case, but the mere possibility of this problem suggests I'm doing something more fundamentally wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitworkflows.html's "Rule: Topic branches", the recommendation seems to be

> - If you find you need new features from the branch other to continue working on your topic, merge other to topic. (However, do not do this "just habitually", see below.)

where "below" reads

> ## Rule: Merge to downstream only at well-defined points
>
> > Do not merge to downstream except with a good reason: upstream API
> >     changes affect your branch; your branch no longer merges to upstream
> >     cleanly; etc.
>
> Otherwise, the topic that was merged to suddenly contains more than a
>   single (well-separated) change. The many resulting small merges will
>   greatly clutter up history. Anyone who later investigates the history
>   of a file will have to find out whether that merge affected the topic
>   in development. An upstream might even inadvertently be merged into a
>   "more stable" branch. And so on.

In summary, that would mean "merge `base` into `stuff` [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) necessary, but never merge `develop` into `stuff` (since it probably contains other features irrelevant to `stuff`)"